# Display fixed div at certain height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a fixed title in a DIV which scrolls under the website until the relevant section. I would like to know how to only have the DIV display once the user scrolls to the needed section.

Comment: Two solutions. Hide/show based on scroll or remove fixed positioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do it with Jquery

Ex -

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 400) {
        $('.youdiclass').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        $('.youdiclass').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect thanks for that. 

Expanded it to be between: 
 scroll >= 700 && scroll <= 2000)

Comment: Is there any way to expand this so the fixed div then STOPS and stays in place at a certain height?

Comment: Use CSS Position fixed